# How to display a change in the text in a textview while the activity is active?

Tags: android, textview

I am having some huge issues and i looked through alot of post about it, but i have yet to find a solution..

I am making a logger activity which appends strings to a .txt on the sdcard. I then abstracts the txt and displays it in a TextView.

Heres the catch. While i can append changes while running, the textview do not want to display the changes in the textview before i go to another activity and then go back again to the log activity. I cannot understand how something so basic as displaying updates text can cause me so much problems.. and also its a very fundamental thing for my application.

Answer (score 0):

try textView.refreshDrawableState();

Ok My Bad, dint read the question properly.
Because you are displaying the text from the file on the sd card, 
 you will have to populate the text every time to the text view, when you change the value in file.
`textView.setText(getTextFromFile());` 
 where `getTextFromFile()` is a method to fetch the text from the file.
I hope you have already done the part to get the text from the file.
If not, please tell.

Comment: That didnt solve my problem. It still wont display the updated textview text.

Comment: Actually it did. I found out the problem is that i somehow needs to keep updating the txt while runing, not only when i go to the activity. Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: I have already the method done, i just need to refactor it abit since im building the string from the text in the on create. Again i cannot thank you enough, this saved my day!